# Swift 'Apollo.Cancellable' does not conform to 'Combine.Cancellable'

Tags: swift, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, combine

I am using Apollo Client subscriptions for my app. I follow the codes here on the documentation from Apollo https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/subscriptions but I keep having an error on when I subscribe to the apollo subscription

`Value of type 'Apollo.Cancellable' does not conform to 'Combine.Cancellable' in assignment`

Here is my code

```
self.subscription = ApolloNetwork.shared.apollo
            .subscribe(subscription: UserBalanceSubscription()) { [weak self] result in
            guard let self = self else {
                return
            }
            
            switch result {
            case .success(let graphQLResult):
                print(graphQLResult)
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

Here is how I declare the var subscription

`private var subscription: Cancellable?`

I am getting confused what causing the issue and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `self.subscription`? What happens if you explicitly declare it as `var subscription: Apollo.Cancellable? = nil`?

Comment: @jnpdx I updated my question and added how I declare var subscription. I will try your suggestion. Please give me a sec. tHank you

Comment: @jnpdx this fix the issue. Thank you so much. if you can comment again your suggestion so I can upvote it. You really save my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a naming collision between modules (`Apollo` and `Combine`) that both have a `Cancellable` type defined.

You can explicitly declare that you want this `Cancellable` to be the one from `Apollo` by doing the following:

```
private var subscription: Apollo.Cancellable?
```